# How to extract all lines under the current, based on a suffix?

Tags: thing-at-point

Currently I'm using `(thing-at-point 'line t)`, however I would like to be able to include the next line(s) as long as they end with a suffix (`\` for example).

How to recursively build a string based on the current line, accumulating all others until the suffix is not present?

Comment: You could define a symbol with properties `forward-op`, `beginning-op` and `end-op` each pointing to a function that will do the proper thing when `thing-at-point` calls them.  You can see the source of `bounds-of-thing-at-point` in `thingatpt.el` to see how these functions will be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to delve into the source of `thing-at-point`, you could simply use a `while` loop. For example:

```elisp
(defun my-extract-lines ()
  "Extract line(s) at point. Multiple lines (below the current) are
extracted if they end with a backslash character. Returns the line(s)
as a string with no properties."    
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((start (line-beginning-position))
           (end start)
           (iterate t)
           (new-end))
      (while iterate
        (setq new-end (line-end-position))
        (if (> new-end end)
            (progn
              (setq end new-end)
              (if (char-equal (char-before end) ?\\)
                  (forward-line)
                (setq iterate nil)))
          (setq iterate nil)))
      (buffer-substring-no-properties start end))))
```

Another alternative is to use a regex, although it is a little bit complicated (due to the number of backslashes needed). For example:

```elisp
(defun my-extract-lines ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((str ""))
    (save-excursion
      (beginning-of-line)
      (when (looking-at "\\(\\(?:.*\\\\\n\\)*[^\n]*[^\\\\]$\\)")
        (setq str (match-string 1)))
     str)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Made a modified version of @håkon-hægland's answer, its mostly the same except:

- It takes a line terminating character.
- White-space after the terminating character is supported
  *(doesn't prevent moving to the next line)*.
- The result is joined into a single line with the terminating-char removed from the end of each line.
- Fixes a bug when the line is at the start of the buffer.

Modified version:

```elisp
(defun my-extract-lines (line-terminate-char)
  "Extract line(s) at point.
Multiple lines (below the current) are extracted
if they end with line-terminate-char.
Returns the line(s) as a joined string,
without the terminator character and no properties."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((start (line-beginning-position))
           (end start)
           (iterate t)
           (new-end))
      (while iterate
        (setq new-end (line-end-position))
        ;; could be more efficient?
        (setq new-end-ws (save-excursion (end-of-line) (skip-syntax-backward "-") (point)))
        (if (> new-end end)
            (progn
              (setq end new-end)
              (setq end-ws new-end-ws)
              (let ((end-ws-before (char-before end-ws)))
                (if (and end-ws-before (char-equal end-ws-before line-terminate-char))
                    (forward-line)
                    (setq iterate nil))))
            (setq iterate nil)))

      ;; OK but we need to remove line-terminate-char and join
      ;; (buffer-substring-no-properties start end)
      (setq line-terminate-str (char-to-string line-terminate-char))
      (mapconcat
       (function
        (lambda (s)
          (string-trim-right (string-remove-suffix line-terminate-str (string-trim s)))))
       (split-string (buffer-substring-no-properties start end) "\n") " "))))
```